# What data structure is better to use to find if sentence consist of unique characters?

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures, dictionary

I'm trying to solve a task and not sure if I'm using suitable data structure for it. My task is to find if sentence consist of unique characters and as a result return boolean value.

Here is my function:

```
bool use_map(string sentence) {
    map<int, string> my_map;

    for (string::size_type i = 0; i <= sentence.length(); i++) {
        unsigned int index = (int)sentence[i];    
        if (my_map.find(index) != my_map.end())
            return false;       
        my_map[index] = sentence[i];
    }

    return true;    
}
```

I found only map structure which is suitable for me. Maybe I miss something?

Maybe it's better to use something like dynamic arrays at `PHP`?

---

I'm trying to use hash table solution.

Comment: Given the small size of a typical alphabet, you'd probably be best off with a `vector<bool>` (or possibly `vector<char>` that you use as bools).

Comment: Why do you need this `my_map[index] = sentence[i];`?

Comment: If there are three or more words, then there'll be two or more blanks; do you really want to count blanks?

Comment: @meh I want to put symbol integer value at map structure if it's not exists. So, my map will have only unique characters. If some symbol exists, it means I put it there before and it's not unique.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I see your point, I will filter for spaces. It's not a mian problem for me for now.

Comment: @viakondratiuk - well, you don't need a map in this case. Or I'm missing something? See my answer for my suggestion.

Comment: I think I'm wrong a little. In this solution I'm trying to use hash tables. And I thought the map is implementation of it.

Comment: @viakondratiuk - nope, `std::map` is not a hash table. For this case, it will be more efficient to use `std::set`, IMO.

Comment: @meh And what is standard way of solving the tasks which should use hash tables? Or it depends?

Comment: `std::hash_map` is a hash map, but the wrong solution for this problem.

Comment: @AlexChamberlain Why do you think it's wrong? I'm reading a book and it's said that try to use for this task hash map.

Comment: Because the set of possible values (26 characters) is so small.

Comment: I do apologise, it is a a `std::unordered_map` or `std::unordered_set`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The other answers suggested `std::set` and that's a solution. BUT, they copy all chars inside the `std::set` and then get the size of the `set`. You don't really need this and you can avoid it, using the return value of `std::set::insert`. Something like:

```
std::set< char > my_set;
for (std::string::size_type ii = 0; ii < sentence.size(); ++ii) 
{
    if( ! my_set.insert( sentence[ ii ] ).second )
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

This way you'll:

- stop on the first duplicated char and you will not copy the whole string (unnecessarily)
- you will avoid the unnecessary cast to `int` in your code
- will save memory - if you don't actually need you `std::map< int, std::string >::second`

Also, make sure you need to "count" all `char`s or you want to skip some of them (like white spaces, commas, question marks, etc)

Comment: Why are you using `ii` instead of `i`. Does it mean something or just question of choice?

Comment: @viakondratiuk - it's a matter of personal choice ( I usually prefer it, because it's easier for highlighting, when you're trying to see where is this index used; for example - suppose it's just `i`, then the `i` in `insert` will be highlighted and I wouldn't want this).

Answer (score 4):

A very simple (but rather memory expensive) way  would be:

```
bool use_map(const std::string& sentence)
{
    std::set<char> chars(sentence.begin(), sentence.end());
    return chars.size() == sentence.size();
}
```

If there's no duplicate chars, the sizes of both string and set will be equal.

@Jonathan Leffler raises a good point in the comments: sentences usualy contain several whitespaces, so this will return `false`. You'll want to filter spaces out. Still, `std::set` should be your container of choice.

**Edit:**

Here's an idea for O(n) solution with no additional memory. Just use a look-up table where you mark if the char was seen before:

```
bool no_duplicates(const std::string& sentence)
{
    static bool table[256];
    std::fill(table, table+256, 0);

    for (char c : sentence) {

        // don't test spaces
        if (c == ' ') continue;
        // add more tests if needed

        const unsigned char& uc = static_cast<unsigned char>(c);
        if (table[uc]) return false;
        table[uc] = true;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Could you explain the "no additional memory" sentence a bit? You are allocating 256 bytes after all, and for an ASCII string you only need 127 **bits** total.

Comment: @Groo Those 256 bytes is allocated staticaly.

Comment: But they are completely redundant, you only need one bit per character to see if it was found earlier.

Comment: @Groo Yes, ASCII has 127 chars, but do you have a guarantee that there won't be chars outside of this range in the string? Re 1 bit/char, is it worth squeezing in 2013? :)

Comment: @zmbq I assume nothing, that's why I defined table big enough to be indexable with every possible value of unsigned char.

Comment: @zmbq: ASCII or Unicode, doesn't make a difference, I was just saying that the "character found" information needs no more than one bit.

Comment: @zmbq Unfortunately, not in C++.

Answer (score 3):

I guess an easy way is to store all the characters in an associative container that does not allow duplicates, such as `std::set`, and check if it contains a single value:

```
#include <set>
#include <string>

bool has_unique_character(std::string const& str)
{
    std::set<char> s(begin(str), end(str));
    return (s.size() == str.size());
}
```

Comment: @meh: Heh, I misunderstood the question: I thought he meant if the string is made up of repetitions of just one character. Me dumb. Will edit.

Answer (score 2):

What about this? There is a case issue of course...

```
bool use_map(const std::string& sentence)
{
    std::vector<bool> chars(26, false);
    for(std::string::const_iterator i = sentence.begin(); i != sentence.end(); ++i) {
        if(*i == ' ' || *i - 'a' > 25 || *i - 'a' < 0) {
            continue;
        } else if(chars[*i - 'a']) {
            return false;
        } else {
            chars[*i - 'a'] = true;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: You need to add some checks. You need to see if *i is an alpha character, and you also need to make it a lowercase character.

Comment: @zmbq Added a couple, it wasn't suppose to be a model solution, just a knock in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

Sort the characters and then look for an adjacent pair of alphabetic characters with both characters equal. Something like this:

```
std::string my_sentence = /* whatever */
std::sort(my_sentence.begin(), my_sentence.end());
std::string::const_iterator it =
    std::adjacent_find(my_sentence.begin(), my_sentence.end());
while (it != my_sentence.end() && isalpha((unsigned char)*it)
    it = std::adjacent_find(++it, my_sentence.end());
if (it == my_sentence.end())
    std::cout << "No duplicates.\n";
else
    std::cout << "Duplicated '" << *it << "'.\n";
```

Comment: That's a bit of an overkill, isn't it? :-)

Comment: Nope. It does everything in place, without any extra memory allocations.

Comment: Sure, but there's that "time complexity" thingy too, and the fact that OP asked for the most appropriate data structure for the job. But true, if space is an issue, than this would be pretty efficient.

Comment: @Groo - have you profiled all the proposed solutions? Especially for the case where there are no duplicates? (And note that most of the tests are wrong, since they will claim that "a b c" has duplicate characters)

Comment: A hashtable, or even better, a plain array gives an `O(n)` **worst case** solution. You are proposing an `O(n*logn)` solution (which probably uses QuickSort under the hood and can degrade to `O(n^2)`). Seriously, what is there to profile?

Comment: @Groo - using the free store is **not** free; lower complexity numbers do not necessarily mean faster algorithms, since we rarely run asymptotically large problems, and overhead matters. And `std::sort` typically uses Stepanov's intro-sort, which does not degenerate.

Comment: I am still inclined to think that a single free store allocation, followed by plain array indexing is much faster than sorting in-place and then looking for adjacent ones, even for only a handful of items, but your C++ knowledge is far beyond mine, so I'll certainly keep this in mind the next time I make a similar assumption.

Answer (score 0):

If you are allowed to use additional memory, use a **hash table**:
 Iterate through the array, check if current element has already been hashed. If yes, you found a repetition. If no, add it to hash. This will be **linear**, but will require additional memory.

If the range of original sequence elements is quite small, instead of hashing you can simply have an array of the range size and do like in a **bucket sort**. For example

```
bool hasDuplicate( string s )
{
   int n = s.size();
   vector<char> v( 256, 0 );
   for( int i = 0; i < n; ++i )
      if( v[ s[ i ] ] ) // v[ hash( s[i] ) ] here in case of hash usage
         return true;
      else
         v[ s[ i ] ] = 1; // and here too
   return false;
}
```

Finally, if you are not allowed to use additional memory, you can **just sort it** and check if two adjacent elements are equal in one pass. This will take **O(nlogn)** time. No need for sets or maps :)

Comment: The sort sounds OK, but the hash table is a terrible idea. Given it's a `std::string`, there are only 26 characters!

Comment: It's what I'm trying to do. To use hash table. I thought whem I'm using map, it's a hash table solution.

Comment: @viakondratiuk: No, map is (in most implementations) based on r-b trees and has logn query/update time, while has is amortized constant.

Comment: @AlexChamberlain: Oh, missed that part and wrote a generic solution. Well if character set is small you can just do a bucket sort, let me edit the answer.

Comment: @viakondratiuk: Actually there's no hash table implementation in stl, you've to write one on your own or use some another library. But if we have, for example, some `int hash(int)` function, in the above code you should just use `v[ hash( s[ i ])]` instead of `v[ s[ i ]]`.

Comment: @GrigorGevorgyan `std::unordered_map` (that's been added to the standard library with C++11) is what you call a hash table.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the fastest possible solution:

```
bool charUsed[256];
bool isUnique(string sentence) {
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < 256; ++i) {
        charUsed[i] = false;
    }

    int n = s.size();
    for(i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        if (charUsed[(unsigned char)sentence[i]]) {
            return false;
        }
        charUsed[(unsigned char)sentence[i]] = true;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: `fastest possible` is a massive claim. You could do a lot more bit twiddling hacks yet. Besides, you missed the simple `memset` the array to 0.